# PHP: How to assign large string with single and double quotes

Tags: php, string

I need to assign large strings in an array. These strings contain single and double quotes as well as backslashes which ***cannot*** be escaped at first.

My code looks like:

```
$myArray = [
    'x' => 'this_is_my_string',
];
```

Now instead of `'this_is_my_string'` I have large strings as:

```
\relative c' {
    \key ees \major
    bes'2 \mf c   bes4. (as8) g4 (as) \breathe
    \bar "|."
```

How to write my code to directly assign large strings like this one?

I have tried with [HEREDOC](https://www.php.net/manual/de/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) and [NOWDOC](https://www.php.net/manual/de/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc) and [addslashes](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.addslashes)/[addcslashed](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.addcslashes.php) but they require to escape at least one of `´`or `"`.

BTW: the large strings are [Lilypond](http://lilypond.org) snippets

Comment: HEREDOC does not require to escape quotes

Comment: You're typing this in or it's assigned to a variable?

Comment: @AbraCadaver: it has to be assigned to a variable. I'm typing this in my PHP editor

Comment: https://3v4l.org/at6Er - nowdoc seems like it works fine, what exactly did you try?

Comment: @AbraCadaver heredoc will interpret the `\r` at the start as a line-break

Comment: You should be able to use the backslash to escape the quotes. Just double the ones already there to escape the already existing backslashes. As I see it, your only problem is going to be converting the incoming string into a suitably quoted code snippet. Shouldn't be difficult to write a small program for that.

Comment: @UncaAlby. there is no incoming string. I'm typing the string in my PHP editor and write PHP code where a variable should by assigned statically.

Comment: @iainn Yep, didnt echo it.

Comment: Type it into a file. Use an editor to globally change every backslash into two backslashes, then every newline into backslash-N-double-quote-dot, then every apostrophe into backslash-apostrophe. Put a double quote at the beginning and at the end. Now if you don't want to do that, I'm afraid I can be of no further assistance, since I only work in the realm of what I *can* do, not what I'd like to see happen.

Comment: I think you may be better off storing in a DB and retrieving or even a text file, then you could write a little function to retrieve and assign.

Comment: @WeSee No, seriously though, this is literally why nowdoc exists - [*The construct is ideal for embedding PHP code or other large blocks of text without the need for escaping.*](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php). You say you already tried it, but **honestly**, [it works](https://3v4l.org/dF7nS), with array assignment and everything. This doesn't need output buffering, databases, work in your editor, or anything else complicated.

Comment: @iainn yes, nowdocs seem to work fine, heredocs don't.

Comment: A nowdoc is exactly what you need: https://3v4l.org/812XN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for [Output Buffering](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php).

```
<?php

ob_start();

?>\relative c' {
    \key ees \major
    bes'2 \mf c   bes4. (as8) g4 (as) \breathe
    \bar "|."<?php

$myArray = [
    'x' => ob_get_clean()
];

?>
```

`ob_start()` initialises output buffering, redirecting STDOUT to the buffer. `ob_end_clean()` will end output buffering, and return the buffer up to that point for use.

Comment: can this be used for a variable assignment? I do not need to output anything but just to assign a variable.

Comment: That's exactly what my snippet is doing. After calling `ob_start()` nothing will be sent to the browser, and will instead be sent to the buffer until you call one of the ending functions. `ob_get_clean()` ends output buffering and returns the buffer for use.

Comment: my question is: how to assign such a string to a variable? not: how to output anything to the browser or elsewhere

Comment: That is exactly what my code is doing. See this in my snippet: `$string = ob_get_clean()` - this is assigning everything that would have been sent to the browser since `ob_start()` was called to `$string`

Comment: ok, I didn't see the assignment. sorry. but how to write this in an array assignment as stated in my question?

Comment: Exactly the same way as any other assignment to an array. I have updated the snippet to correlate to the code in your question.

Comment: Your answer seems the only feasible solution for my question. Thank you, I used it and it works.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use a nowdoc.

> A nowdoc is specified similarly to a heredoc, but no parsing is done
>   inside a nowdoc. The construct is ideal for embedding PHP code or
>   other large blocks of text without the need for escaping.

```
<?php

$myArray = [
    'x' => <<<'STR'
      \relative c' {
    \key ees \major
    bes'2 \mf c   bes4. (as8) g4 (as) \breathe
    \bar "|."
STR
];

echo $myArray['x'];
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Anyone downvoting needs to explain why they think that it isn't.

Comment: See comment from @AbraCadaver to my question: heredoc will interpret the \r at the start as a line-break. So this solution doesn't work fully.

Comment: @WeSee - This answer doesn't mention heredoc, it's about nowdoc. Nowdoc was designed for situations like this. You say you tried it in your original question, but never said exactly how. It works, as several people (including me) told you.

Comment: @iainn: Well, you are right. Nowdoc works, too. Thank you for your efforts. http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b6aab3217fc71875b17f2f6a20a3905240c55e80